# Mac OS X can't boot after renaming "/usr" system folder

Tags: macos, boot

Yesterday i tried to change the `/usr` folder with an old one saved in Time Machine,

I type this in the terminal (to keep a copy of /usr folder) :

```
# mv /usr /usr-copy
```

After that nothing work, I decided to reboot (and I've forgotten to rename the /usr-copy in /usr, I was tired), so now **there's is no /usr folder** at all!

I have this message on each reboot :

```
You need to restart yout computer. 
Hold down the Power button until it turns off, then press the Power button again
```

I cannot access to any other things like a menu... just the message
reboot and hold f11 doesn't work.

**Is there a way to access the terminal, where I can type *"# mv /usr-copy /usr"* ?**

Comment: This is really a question for superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: Where did you expect the mv command to be? Anyway, belong on superuser.com

Comment: I did something like that once - fortunately it was in installation, so I just blew away what I'd done and reinstalled.

Comment: @Benjamin - Definitely superuser. This is not a question for serverfault (Or Stackoverflow).

Comment: Holy crap, what were you thinking?

Comment: My first thought was to respond "Doctor! I can't stand after I blew both of my legs off!" but I see you actually understand what you did, you just weren't awake at the time...

Comment: possible duplicate of [HELP! Overzealous `mv` renamed my /usr/lib folder](http://superuser.com/questions/168146/help-overzealous-mv-renamed-my-usr-lib-folder)

Comment: Awkward problem is awkward.

Answer (score 12):

You can boot from your install disk.  When you boot from the disk, you will be asked to choose your language.

After choosing your language, a desktop will appear and the "Utilities" item in the menu bar will contain an entry for the Terminal.

Use this menu start the Terminal app and move, rename, or replace the missing directories.

Comment: Clarification: once you're past the initial choose language screen, the installer will have a Utilities menu with Terminal among the available choices.

Answer (score 4):

I would remove the harddrive and mount it in another machine, and rename the catalog, and then return the harddrive to your original machine.

Answer (score 2):

Others have  given good suggestions on how to actually boot the machine.

For future reference, if you, for some reason, do this again, (or if you actually DO want to swap the two /usr hierarchies... if you add /usr-cpy/bin to your path, you should still have access to all of your utilities...

Comment: This won't necessarily avoid trouble -- just because the temporary binaries directory is in *your* path doesn't mean the various background daemons that depend on it won't fail horribly...

Answer (score 1):

If removing the harddrive isn't an option, then consider restoring from your last time machine backup, and then redoing your changes when you aren't too tired.

Holding down the command key while booting alters the boot sequence - it may get you to where you need to be.  There are other special-key-during-boot tricks too; I don't have them memorized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> during start-up to enter the Single User mode, this could help especially because you don't seem to have an install disk?

Answer (score 0):

Either use a rescue-DVD or something to move /usr back or reinstall OSX completely.

You should *NEVER EVER* mv /usr. Copy it if you need. For Unix a big portion of the binaries and stuff you need are in /usr, so if you mv it, you'll practically kill your OSX Installation.